# MVI - fix state duplication

Tags: android, performance

I'm trying to implement the `MVI pattern` into my application, but I'm facing the issue of the state getting duplicated for actions

> this is my state model:

```
data class FeatureState(
    val loading: Boolean = false,
    val error: CommonError? = null,
    val textList: List<String>? = null,
    val dataModel: PojoModel? = null
)
```

and in my view model updating the `uiState` as follows

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(initialState)

 _uiState.update {
    copy(
        loading = false,
        textList = texts,
        error = null
    )
 }

 _uiState.update {
    copy(
        loading = false,
        dataModel = model,
        error = null
    )
 }
```

and in my fragment, I consume `uiState` as follows

```
private fun observeUi() = collectFlow {
    launch { viewModel.uiState.collect(::handleScreenState) }
}

private fun handleScreenState(state: FeatureState) = with(state) {
    showProgress(loading)
    error?.handleError()
    state.textList?.let { updateList(it) }
    state.dataModel?.let { updateUi(it) }
}
```

if I call two APIs and one updating `textList` and the other updating `dataModel`, in that case, I'm getting duplicate for action in the collect for both `textList` & `dataModel`

for clarification:
first API updated the state `textList` and the second API call updated `dataModel` while collecting the `uiState` the action is handled for both States

So, what I'm looking for is how to handle that so it's fire-only updates for the needed state, not both states.

simple hint: it's happening too with `loading` state

Comment: isn't this expected, since you are updating flow and returning the complete object, to distinguish what got changed 1 solution can be to add a new enum that will tell you what got changed and while updating state make sure to emit what got changed and act on ui accordingly

Comment: you are right, but, it's the same as making the state as sealed class I need to keep using flow and find solution to it without sealed/enum class

Comment: but the thing you are going into seems practically impossible, as if you have a object's flow then ofc everytime you update the flow whole object will be emitted, it's very well suited for compose due to recomposition and all stuff but in xml, it's redundant to update everything

Comment: @pseudoankit I ended by using a single event handle for each value but, it's a weird solution, do you recommend any other solution to work with XML yes we are planning to use compose in the near future